# CSS justify-content, align-items and align-content not working

Tags: css, flexbox

So as I am learning flexbox, i am experimenting with justify-content: flex-end and it comes to no avail, I want to use flexbox to move the content of the header tags to the right hand side without using padding.

My code is uploaded on gitub on: https://github.com/SmileyFaceImoji/Landing-Page

I highlighted the div that holds the header links in green to see if I didn't reference the proper tag and I did

The goal is that I make a landing page similar to this: https://cdn.statically.io/gh/TheOdinProject/curriculum/81a5d553f4073e593d23a6ab00d50eef8620796d/foundations/html_css/project/imgs/01.png

Comment: did you see (https://roadmap.sh/frontend) ? or more specifically (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) ?

Comment: or (https://css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/css-flexbox-poster.png) that poster is awesome

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you wanted but from looking at your image I believe you wanted this

Just add following codes

This codes places your items at end of your flex box + makes sure your items don't go too wide on large screen

If you have smaller screen, you can test this using <kbd>command & -</kbd> on Mac, <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>CTR</kbd> on Windows

```
.hero {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

.header-links {
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```